# iframe window top location issue. iframe loads over and over again

Tags: iframe

When my iframe loads I need parent page to load different content(header,footer) while iframe its still there. I added to iframe :

```
window.top.location = "http://mysite.com";
```

It loads the new parent page but its reloading over and over again.
How can I enable only one load/iframe load, or some solution.

I have tried with

```
window.onload = function() {
if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
}
```

}

but it does nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to load different parent page of iframe only if the actual parent page of the iframe is preset link ?

Comment: so you are asking if you can load a different page if the page you want to load is in a "preset link list"? well, remember that the iframe is just a component inside the parent page, you can load another parent page with a simple redirect but the new page must have the same iframe inside!

Answer (score 0):

you just can't reload the iframe parent only without reloading the iframe too! If you want to change some content in parent page you must do it with javascript from the parent page and not the iframe.
And if you want to catch the "iframe loaded event" you must do it from inside the iframe. Looks like an impossible situation but you can still do it!

You need to let iframe and parent page comunicate, and you can do it with html5 postmessage (works even if parent and iframe are in different domains!). If you need to have IE7 compatibility too you can use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/) javascript library instead of postMessage, just search for example in their site.

Simply do a postMessage from iFrame when `jQuery(document).ready()` (or any similar event) is triggered, the parent page must have a listner waiting for this message for trigger the header/footer/anything change event.

Comment: All I need is for the iframe to trigger only one refresh of the parent page.

Comment: Then how can I load different parent page if certain page is loaded in iframe or certain word found in iframe ?

Comment: if you need only 1 refresh you can write some variable in the cookie to remember if you already refreshed the page. Remember to re-initialize that variable after the single refresh!
and.. you can't reload the parent page only. If you reload the parent you reload the iframe too

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Maybe you can writte a little example here.

Comment: import jQuery, import jQuery cookies plugin ( https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie ), write a cookie with "$.cookie('refreshNeeded', '0');" and read that cookie value with "$.cookie('refreshNeeded');", pretty easy

Comment: Pretty easy for you:) I have this iframe where people login to members area. All I need is to convert login in logout from parent page after they login in iframe. After login iframe loads my account page. If I refresh the page(parent) it loads the correct parent page (because it loads 'already login' page where I already added window.top.location = "http://www.site.com"; ) . All I need is one refresh from parent page after people are logged in iframe.

Comment: i can't understand why you used an iframe for login in your site, but after login you should refresh both parent page and iframe. I think the ideal solution is a simple javascript that send a postMessage from iframe to parent page, so when parent page receive the postMessage he can write "logout" and relative href over "login". But, really, you shouldn't use iframe for this. Send messages with easyXDM is really easy, read this: http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/

Comment: The iframe site its really ugly in design terms, hard to make it from scratch as is fully php. Actually there is another image button that changes from 'log in' to 'my account' (preset it in css file). I can't trigger parent page refresh if iframe contain a specified word (i.e. account)?